# Сортировка массива

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Помогите отсортировать массив.
Нужна сортировка по [count] от наибольшего значения.

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pid] => 343215590

                    [likes] => Array
                        (
                            [user_likes] => 0
                            [count] => 38
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pid] => 343215587

                    [likes] => Array
                        (
                            [user_likes] => 0
                            [count] => 60
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: @RapCore, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

[usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

Comment: краткость — чья-то там то ли сестра, то ли жена. это понятно. но зачем подавать дурной пример начинающим «ответчикам»? хотя бы пример использования приведите, пожалуйста.